# Why does my Tabu search step score keep decreasing in REPRODUCIBLE mode, but not in FAST_ASSERT mode

Tags: optaplanner

I have modeled an overconstrained rostering problem and implemented incremental score calculations based on constraint streams. Strangely enough, my local search performance is very poor when I set the environment mode to REPRODUCIBLE, but not when I set it to
FAST_ASSERT.

I ran the benchmarker with the following configuration:

```
<plannerBenchmark xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark/benchmark.xsd">

    <benchmarkDirectory>/Users/martijn/Downloads/benchmark</benchmarkDirectory>
    <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
        <solver>
            <solutionClass>nl.pompkracht.rosteringengine.optaplanner.adapter.Roster</solutionClass>
            <entityClass>nl.pompkracht.rosteringengine.optaplanner.adapter.ShiftAssignment</entityClass>
            <domainAccessType>GIZMO</domainAccessType>
            <scoreDirectorFactory>
                <constraintProviderClass>nl.pompkracht.rosteringengine.optaplanner.adapter.RosterConstraintProvider
                </constraintProviderClass>
            </scoreDirectorFactory>
            <termination>
                <minutesSpentLimit>1</minutesSpentLimit>
            </termination>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
        </solver>
    </inheritedSolverBenchmark>

    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>Fast assert</name>
        <solver>
            <environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode>
            <localSearch>
                <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>Reproducible</name>
        <solver>
            <environmentMode>REPRODUCIBLE</environmentMode>
            <localSearch>
                <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>

</plannerBenchmark>
```

In FAST_ASSERT mode, the medium score increases over time, while in REPRODUCIBLE mode it does not

[image: Score over time]

When I turn on debug logging, I can see that in REPRODUCIBLE mode, the step scores keep decreasing over time, and it never finds a new best score:

```
2022-07-07 19:32:09.125  INFO 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] .c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase : Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (648), best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), score calculation speed (9232/sec), step total (288).
2022-07-07 19:32:09.444 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (0), time spent (967), score (-1hard/-47medium/-279647soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1000), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:09.574 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (1), time spent (1097), score (-14hard/-46medium/-281215soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1007), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:09.701 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (2), time spent (1224), score (-29hard/-47medium/-279567soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1016), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:09.818 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (3), time spent (1341), score (-36hard/-47medium/-279567soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1018), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:09.952 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (4), time spent (1475), score (-45hard/-47medium/-279567soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1027), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:10.084 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (5), time spent (1607), score (-53hard/-47medium/-279567soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1038), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:10.226 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (6), time spent (1749), score (-69hard/-47medium/-279439soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1051), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:10.370 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (7), time spent (1893), score (-74hard/-48medium/-276959soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1064), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:10.511 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (8), time spent (2034), score (-91hard/-48medium/-274943soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1061), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:10.647 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (9), time spent (2170), score (-96hard/-48medium/-275199soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1069), picked move ...
2022-07-07 19:32:10.781 DEBUG 32658 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase        :     LS step (10), time spent (2304), score (-106hard/-47medium/-277375soft),     best score (0hard/-47medium/-281887soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1086), picked move ...
```

Could there be some issue with my score constraints that might cause this behavior?

Update:

I was able to pinpoint the problematic behavior to one particular constraint:

```kotlin
fun simultaneousAssigmentConflict(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Constraint =
    constraintFactory.forEach(ShiftConflict::class.java).join(
        ShiftAssignment::class.java, Joiners.equal({ it -> it.shiftOne }, { it.shift.shiftId })
    ).ifExists(ShiftAssignment::class.java,
        Joiners.equal({ conflict, _ -> conflict.shiftTwo }, { it.shift.shiftId }),
        Joiners.filtering { _, assignmentOne, assignmentTwo ->
            assignmentOne.worker?.workerId?.let { it == assignmentTwo.worker?.workerId } ?: false
        }).penalize("Assignment of other shift during this shift or during resting period", ONE_HARD)
```

When I replace `constraintFactory.forEach` with the deprecated `constraintFactory.from` method, the local search works fine in REPRODUCIBLE mode.

The same applies when I replace the `ifExists` filter with a join:

```kotlin
fun simultaneousAssigmentConflict(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Constraint =
    constraintFactory.forEach(ShiftConflict::class.java)
        .join(ShiftAssignment::class.java, Joiners.equal({ it -> it.shiftOne }, { it.shift.shiftId })).join(
            ShiftAssignment::class.java,
            Joiners.equal({ conflict, _ -> conflict.shiftTwo }, { it.shift.shiftId }),
            Joiners.filtering { _, assignmentOne, assignmentTwo ->
                assignmentOne.worker?.workerId?.let { it == assignmentTwo.worker?.workerId } ?: false
            }).penalize("Assignment of other shift during this shift or during resting period", ONE_HARD)
```

Update (see [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246259/discussion-between-crimsoncricket-and-lukas-petrovicky)):  Lukáš Petrovický was able to track this down to an upstream bug in Drools:

> Ok, this was a challenge. :-) I finally tracked it down to a bug in
> Drools. We have a fix upstream, hopefully it finds its way to
> OptaPlanner 8.25.0.Final.

Comment: What happens if you don't use TABU_SEARCH? What happens if you don't use GIZMO domain access type? I'm having a hard time coming up with any sort of explanation, so I'd like to eliminate some variables first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lukáš, I set `<domainAccessType>REFLECTION</domainAccessType>` and `<localSearchType>LATE_ACCEPTANCE</localSearchType>` 

The results were kind of similar: in FAST_ASSERT mode the medium score increased over time (1 minute). In REPRODUCIBLE mode the local search only took a single step. 

When I look a the trace logs, I see that the move scores generally deteriorate within that step, almost as if they are affected by previously evaluated moves?

...LocalSearchDecider :  Move index (126053), score (-728hard/-45medium/-289079soft), accepted (false)

Comment: FULL_ASSERT should be able to uncover any sort of score corruption, even those that FAST_ASSERT won't catch. Have you run FULL_ASSERT for a few minutes?

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid that the FULL_ASSERT mode eliminates the problematic behavior, similar to the FAST_ASSERT mode. I have been running it for 20 minutes now without any errors or warnings

Comment: That tells me that the constraints are most likely fine. I'm afraid I have no idea what could be going on - if you can get me a piece of code that I can execute on my end, I can look into it further.

Comment: My code currently requires quite a bit of environment setup to run. I can try to put together something that you could run in isolation, but that will take me some time.

Meanwhile I found something interesting: when I change `constraintFactory.forEach` to the deprecated `constraintFactory.from` it runs fine in REPRODUCIBLE mode.

Comment: FWIW `constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars` also has the problematic behaviour in REPRODUCIBLE mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246259/discussion-between-crimsoncricket-and-lukas-petrovicky).

Comment: Please run with NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT and report back what that does. Unlike FAST/FULL_ASSERT, that mode doesn't trigger a calculateScore after a step, so in this aspect its like REPRODUCIBLE. But it does check for score corruption on the moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary from [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246259/discussion-between-crimsoncricket-and-lukas-petrovicky):

It's a score corruption.

Using environmentMode FAST_ASSERT or FULL_ASSERT caused the issue not to reproduce. Those have side-effects.

**Using NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT reproduces the issue** (like REPRODUCIBLE) but also detect the score corruption immediately as it happens (unlike REPRODUCIBLE), explaining why.

Further investigation revealed this to be a bug in Drools and the fix for it will likely surface in OptaPlanner 8.25.0.Final.